# Подсчет уникальных чисел в массиве без ArrayList

Tags: java, массивы

Программа должна подсчитывать уникальные чисел в массиве, например

```
input:
{1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6}

output:
2
```

Код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] znamka = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 5};
    System.out.println(Diff(znamka));
}

public static int Diff(int[] znamka){
        ArrayList<Integer> ArrUnique = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int values=0;
        for (int num : znamka) {
            if (!ArrUnique.contains(num)) ArrUnique.add(num);
        }
        values = ArrUnique.size();
        if (values == 1) values = 0;
        return values;
    }
```

Пожалуйста подскажите, можно ли написать без ArrayList, если да, то как?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
long uniqueCount = Arrays.stream(znamka)
                         .boxed()
                         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                         .entrySet()
                         .stream()
                         .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                         .filter(v -> v == 1)
                         .count();
```

Comment: Конструкцию `entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue` можно заменить на `values().stream()`

Answer (score 0):

Предложу не самый рациональный, но тоже вариант.Для начала отсортировать массив, потом пройтись по нему циклом, проверяя, равен ли текущий элемент предыдущему. И если нет, то инкрементировать счетчик. Ну и отдельным случаем проверить равенство первого элемента массива второму.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел еще один ответ на свой же вопрос)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int[] znamka = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 5};
System.out.println(pocet(znamka));
}

 public static int pocet(int[] znamka) {
    int flag = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < znamka.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < znamka.length; j++)
        {
            if(i != j)
            {
                if(znamka[i] != znamka[j])
                {
                    flag = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(flag == 1)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

На днях решал идентичную задачу, решил её через множество (set).
Одно из свойств множества - элементы в нём не могут повторяться, поэтому добавление элементов массива в множество решает ваш вопрос. 
Пример кода:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] arr = {1, 1, 5, 3};
    Set<Integer> arrSet = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arrSet.add(arr[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(arrSet.size());
}
```

Единственное что, если вдальнейшем нужно будет работать с элементами массива, не являщихся примитивами, не забудьте переопределить equals() и hashCode() для корректной работы программы. :)